# Difference between node and nodejs

Tags: node.js

I know this is something  confusing. but

```
node --version
v5.2.0
```

and

```
nodejs --version
v0.10.25
```

gives different versions? What is the difference between them?

Comment: Is it just perhaps an alias on your machine that points to a different installation of node?

Comment: `which node`, vs which `nodejs`

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed node as a not-clean installation, and instead of upgrading the node version on your computer, you've added a different version and kept the old one.
Installing 32bit/64bit versions might explain this as well.

If you want to get everything in order, go to Add/Remove programs, remove all your node versions, make sure nothing is left in Program Files / Program Files (x86) and install a clean installation.

Comment: Even its the same for me both different versions

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you have NodeJS once not twice like you.

I recommend you to uninstall and retry a clean install: https://nodejs.org/en/